# Solving $\int \frac{e^x}{2e^x + \sqrt{e^x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

(I Prefer to open new question because those are my homework and i want to understand my way)

In my homework i need to solve the integral:

$$
\int \frac{e^x}{2e^x + \sqrt{e^x}}dx
$$

I tried the substitution method:

$$
t = e^x \Rightarrow dt = e^x dx
$$

Therefore i get:

$$
\int \frac{dt}{2t + \sqrt{t}}
$$

But what now? How can i proceed? Is this the right way?

I prefer hint and not whole answer - those are my homework

Thanks.

Comment: How about $$\sqrt{e^x}=t\implies e^x=?$$

Comment: Got it. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Following your work:

$$\int \frac{dt}{2t + \sqrt{t}} = \int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(2\sqrt{t}+1)} = \ln(2\sqrt{t}+1)+c$$

This is because the derivative of $2\sqrt{t}+1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ is present so essentially we have $$\int \frac{d(2\sqrt{t}+1)}{2\sqrt{t}+1}$$

whose answer is $\ln(2\sqrt{t}+1)$

Comment: Thats nice, just for practice i did your way and the other way - got the same, thanks

Comment: But i got it without the "2" in the beginning of the $\ln$.

Comment: @Alon Yeah you are right its inside

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

- Make the substitution $u=\sqrt t$ in your last integral.
- Or do at the beginning the substitution $t=\sqrt{e^x}$ instead of $t=e^x$.

Comment: Thank you, i got it.